# Is there any way to animate a grid of changing colors onto text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
    <div id="title-pg">
      <h1 id="title">etch-a-sketch</h1>
      <div id="title-grid-ctn"></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
let titlePage = document.querySelector("#title-grid-ctn");

createTitleGrid();

function createTitleGrid() {
  for (i = 0; i < Math.pow(10, 2); i++) {
    const titleGrid = document.createElement("div");
    titleGrid.classList.add("title-grid");
    titlePage.appendChild(titleGrid);
  }
}

const titleGrid = titlePage.querySelectorAll(".title-grid");

titleGrid.forEach((titleGrid) => {
  titleGrid.animate(
    [
      {
        backgroundColor: `rgb(${rdmNumber()}, ${rdmNumber()}, ${rdmNumber()})`,
      },
      {
        backgroundColor: `rgb(${rdmNumber()}, ${rdmNumber()}, ${rdmNumber()})`,
      },
    ],
    {
      duration: 2000,
      iterations: Infinity,
      delay: 0,
      easing: "linear",
      direction: "alternate",
    }
  );
});
```

I'd like to clip the text over the grid of changing colors, but I can't figure out a way to cut the rest of the grid out.

Is this what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your text on top of the grid and use `mix-blend-mode: lighten;` in your CSS. Take a look at this live snippet:

```js
let titlePage = document.querySelector("#title-grid-ctn");

createTitleGrid();

function createTitleGrid() {
  for (i = 0; i < Math.pow(10, 2); i++) {
    const titleGrid = document.createElement("div");
    titleGrid.classList.add("title-grid");
    titlePage.appendChild(titleGrid);
  }
}

function rdmNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
}

const titleGrid = titlePage.querySelectorAll(".title-grid");

titleGrid.forEach((titleGrid, i) => {
  titleGrid.animate(
    [
      {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      },
      {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
      },
    ],
    {
      duration: 2000,
      iterations: Infinity,
      delay: -i * 1000,
      easing: "linear",
      direction: "alternate",
    }
  );
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#title-pg {
  position: relative;
}

#title-grid-ctn {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.title-grid {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

#title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  font: 900 4em sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="title-pg">
  <div id="title-grid-ctn"></div>
  <h1 id="title">etch-a-sketch</h1>
</div>
```